# Object Placeholder?

Tags: java, oop, object

Say I made Objects

```
Location house, home;
```

and I want there to be a placeholder where

```
placeholder = house;
```

or

```
placeholder = home;
```

How would I do this? I tried `Location placeholder;` but after testing it I reasoned that you can't set two Objects equal to each other. I need the placeholder object so I can plug the different Objects of the same type into methods.

Comment: Are you interested in having both objects point to the same location in memory, or would you like the placeholder to be an exact duplicate, but point to a different location in memory?

Comment: Sure you can set two objects to equal each other. This would mean that changes to `placeholder` is reflected in the object it is referring to, which would be either `house` or `home`.

Comment: I am trying to make them share the same memory.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I figured at first. I'll take my question to the next level.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Do not edit a question in a way that would invalidate existing answers.  Question rolled back.  Please start a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a minimal class:

```
Class Foo {
    public int x;
    public Foo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And you create two instances:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo(1);
Foo foo2 = new Foo(2);
```

And a third, "placeholder"

```
Foo placeholder = foo1;
```

Now, if you changed anything via the `placeholder` variable, it would be reflected in the `foo1` variable as well. This is because Java is referenced by address. Meaning:

```
foo1.x = 9;
// placeholder.x is now 9
placeholder.x = 99;
// foo1.x is now 99
```

Finally, if you would change what instance `placeholder` is referring to, you could do this, and any new changes are now applied to the other instance.

```
placeholder = foo2;
placeholder.x = 0;
// foo2.x is now 0
// foo1.x is still 99 from the previous code segment
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually after a declaration like

```
Location house;
```

the variable `house` is a reference that may hold the memory location of a `Location` object living in the heap.

An assignment like

```
placeholder = house
```

just makes the reference `placeholder` point to the same memory location as `house`.

So you do not set two objects equal to each other, but rather make two references point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

None of these are objects.  They are all pointers.

This is a typical example of the confusion caused by java's attempts to sell itself as a pointer-free language, and by extension as a safe language.  Java only begins to make sense once you realize that in java, everything (except primitives) is a pointer.

`Location house, home;` does not declare any objects at all. It declares two pointers to `Location`, both are `null`.

Objects are obtained with `new Location()`, so you can have the following:

```
Location house = new Location();
Location home = new Location();

Location placeholder = house;
placeholder = home;
```

Comment: Hey, mind taking a look at the question? I fixed it, and it might just have something to do with the issue you stated. However, I'm fairly sure I forced the Location newLocation (which is the placeholder) to be YourHometown, which means it shouldn't ever return null.